# Due to Mixed Content error I am unable to load my grid

Tags: jquery, mixed-content

Error:

> Mixed Content: The page at 'https://Rportal.Rahul.in/Revenue/RMAPMAP'
> was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure script
> 'http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js'. This request has been
> blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

I changed URL from http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js to https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js, still it's didn't worked.

Comment: What error/problem do you see when using the https version?

Comment: Any reason you use such an old version of jquery? Latest version is now 3.6.1

Comment: @Pete I used latest version but it won't work

Comment: @DBS please check : : Mixed Content: The page at 'https://Rportal.Rahul.in/Revenue/RMAPMAP' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure script 'http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

Comment: That sounds like your haven't actually updated the link, have you made sure the change was applied and you're not receiving the old version of your site? (E.g. make sure the old page isn't cached in your browser)

Comment: I solved this issue by calling Ajax within Datatable...   table = $('#RMAP_Map_Table').DataTable({
            "ajax": {
                url: '/Revenue/RMAP_Grid',
                data: param,
                type: "POST",
                dataSrc: "",
            },